# How to set the setCheckedState of a QTreeWidget child's child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget that has a hidden root, 2 children as headers, and 2 children underneath those children.

```
ROOT (HIDDEN)
  |
  |- HEADER 1 (CHILD, NOT CHECKABLE)
  |     |
  |     |- ITEM 11 (CHILD, CHECKABLE)
  |     |- ITEM 12 (CHILD, CHECKABLE)
  |
  |- HEADER 2 (CHILD)
  |     |
  |     | - ITEM 21 (CHILD, CHECKABLE)
  |     | - ITEM 22 (CHILD, CHECKABLE)
```

Using a variable from the `item = {}` dictionary I need to `setCheckState` of HEADER 1, ITEM 12. Currently I track the current selected label using `self.CurrentIndexLabel`, although that is probably irrelevant in this example. I have populated the tree like such:

```
TreeList = ({
    'Header1': (('Item11', 'Item12', )),
    'Header2': (('Item21', 'Item22', )),
})

item = {'Item12': {'ItemEnabled': 1}}  # 0 = No, 1 = Yes

for key, value in TreeList.items():
    parent = QTreeWidgetItem(self.ListTreeView, [key])
    for val in value:
        child = QTreeWidgetItem([val])
        child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.addChild(child)
```

Initially, I need to set whether the item is checked, or unchecked based on the `item = {}` dictionary that tacks variables for each item, and when the user unchecks the item, I need to change the `item = {}` dictionary to reflect whether or not the item is enabled.

I assume I need to use signal and slots to detect the change, but I can't seem to figure out how to flag an item in the list as checked, and I'm not sure how to reflect a user checking or unchecking an item in `TreeList`.

It would be ideal if I can track the checking or unchecking using 1 and 0 to update the dictionary `item = {}` with it's current state.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I'm new to python, so please bear with me. I'm using Python 3.6 and PyQt5

Comment: I think the structure of the `item` dict is inapropriate. Using `QTreeWidgetItem` value as a key would be easier, so a dict like `item = {'Item12': {'ItemEnabled': True}}`.
Also, this key can be stored using `Qt.UserRole` instead of `Qt.DisplayRole`

Comment: This is a very simplistic version of the dictionary that I'm using, it is structured how you suggest as I have 20 items I need to track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `QTreeWidgetItem` is checked or unchecked, a `QTreeWidget.itemChanged(item, column)` signal is emitted. So you can use it and then update your `item` dict in the slot.

And as said in a comment, I think the structure of the `item` dict you use is inapropriate. Using `QTreeWidgetItem` text value as a key (or still better, the `QTreeWidgetItem` object itself) would be easier, so a dict like `item = {'Item12': {'ItemEnabled': True}}`

For example :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class MyApplication(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApplication, self).__init__()
        self.item = {'Item12': {'ItemEnabled': True}}
        self.setupUi()

        TreeList = ({
            'Header1': ('Item11', 'Item12',),
            'Header2': ('Item21', 'Item22',),
        })

        for key, value in TreeList.items():
            parent = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget, [key])
            for val in value:
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([val])
                child.setFlags(child.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                child.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked if val in self.item else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                parent.addChild(child)

        self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.treeWidgetItemChanged)

    def setupUi(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def treeWidgetItemChanged(self, widgetItem, column):
        print("Item {} is checked: {}".format(widgetItem, widgetItem.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Checked))
        itemName = str(widgetItem.text(column))
        try:
            self.item[itemName]['ItemEnabled'] = widgetItem.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Checked
        except KeyError:
            self.item[itemName] = {'ItemEnabled': widgetItem.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Checked}

        print(self.item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApplication()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That solves the problem when a user checks or unchecks the checkbox, but what about reading from the `item = {}' dictionary and applying the `ItemEnabled` value to the checkboxes of the QTreeView? On a side note, I'm using PyQt5 and Python 3, so your answer needed to be modified in order to work.

Comment: It's done too (I've edited my answer many times :p). I do not have PyQt5 installed but I bet It works without much effort.

Comment: This works, but it still doesn't really give me the control I was hoping for. Is there a way to call the `treeWidgetItemChanged` without using `self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.treeWidgetItemChanged)`? The reason I ask is because `self.treeWidget`, in my case, is instantiated before `self.item`. I assume the answer is no since `widgetItem` is an object passed from `self.treeWidget`. I might need a new question for that part.

Comment: Why you would to call the `treeWidgetItemChanged` slot yourself ? Is it for populating the `item` dict ?

Comment: I have a section of code that is for initializing all the default values. Under this code, the `self.item` dictionary is created, and the initial values for `ItemEnabled` are set. After that point, I need to update `self.treeWidget` so it the checks reflect the current `ItemEnabled` state. In my case, `self.treeWidget` is defined in the layout section of my code. I'm trying to keep things organized as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why you would call the `treeWidgetItemChanged` slot. This slot update `self.item` dict according to user action. If you need to set the initial state of checkboxes, you just need to iterate over `self.item` once the inital values for `ItemEnabled` are set and use `QTreeWidgetItem.setCheckState()` to set checkbox state. If it do not fit your needs or if you do not understand how to do that, I encourage you to edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: @AaronTomason What is the problem with this solution?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm still trying to adapt it to my code, but that's on me, busy day. The first part works as intended, the only other thing I'm trying to do is set the check state from another method. `self.itemWidget.setCheckState()` in this case, although I'm not entirely sure how to explicitly select which child to apply the check to. I have not had a chance to test @Loïc suggestion yet, but this does answer my question for the most part. Answer updated to reflect that, and if need be I will ask a new question once I've done some research.